# Mysql create a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger, but there was an error somewhere, and I have no idea how to write correct.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Authorization(
userID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
login VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
numberOfFailedAttempts SMALLINT,
lastLogin TIMESTAMP,
lockedAccount BOOLEAN
);


INSERT INTO Authorization SELECT NULL, "test1", SHA2('pass1', 256), 1, NULL,  FALSE;
INSERT INTO Authorization SELECT NULL, "test2", SHA2('pass2', 256), 1, NULL, FALSE;
INSERT INTO Authorization SELECT NULL, "test3", SHA2('pass3', 256), 1, NULL, FALSE;
INSERT INTO Authorization SELECT NULL, "test4", SHA2('pass4', 256), 1, NULL, FALSE;</code>
```

I would to create a trigger when update the user check `numberOfFailedAttempts`. If `numberOfFailedAttempts`  > 3, then change `lockedAccount` to true.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER UPDATE ON `numberOfFailedAttempts`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (`numberOfFailedAttempts` > 3) THEN
UPDATE SET `lockedAccount` = 1 WHERE 1, LIMIT 1;
END;
```

The error is:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET `lockedAccount` = 1 WHERE 1, LIMIT 1' at line 5</code>
```

Can someone please help me?

Edit:

In this code I had the same error.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER UPDATE ON `numberOfFailedAttempts`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (`numberOfFailedAttempts` > 3) THEN
UPDATE `Authorization` SET `lockedAccount` = '1' WHERE     `Authorization`.`userID` = OLD.`userID`;
END;
```

Edit:

I changed code and it worked.

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 BEFORE UPDATE ON Authorization
FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.`numberOfFailedAttempts` > 3 THEN
SET NEW.`lockedAccount` = 1;
END IF;//
```

Comment: The error indicate that, you need to specify the table name after `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in the code still have the same error.

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER UPDATE ON Authorization.numberOfFailedAttempts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (`numberOfFailedAttempts` > 3) THEN
UPDATE SET OLD.`lockedAccount` = 1 WHERE 1, LIMIT 1;
END;

Comment: You set table name at wrong place, Try this: `UPDATE Authorization SET lockedAccount = 1 WHERE 1, LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I had an error in line 5.

    CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER UPDATE ON     `numberOfFailedAttempts`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    IF (`numberOfFailedAttempts` > 3) THEN
    UPDATE Authorization SET lockedAccount = 1 WHERE 1, LIMIT 1;
    END;

Comment: Check my Answer. May be It will sort out your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER //
   
    CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER UPDATE ON Authorization
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF (numberOfFailedAttempts > 3) THEN
           UPDATE Authorization SET lockedAccount = 1 WHERE 1 LIMIT 1;
        END IF;
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 AFTER UPDATE ON `numberOfFailedAttempts`
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 IF (`numberOfFailedAttempts` > 3) THEN
 UPDATE Authorization SET `lockedAccount` = 1 WHERE 1, LIMIT 1;
 END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I had an error in line 5.